# How do I display number of degrees in 1 Radian Python 3.3

Tags: python

I'm a beginner when it comes to python, and I have been stuck on this problem that is probably very easy, but I am having a massive brain fart with this. I am trying to display the number of degrees in one radian. Any Help is appreciated

```
print(math.radians(math.degrees(1)))
```

That's what I have right now, and I've been messing with it for a while now. I just cant get it.

Comment: So what did you actually get? What did you expect?

Comment: I expected 57.2957, and i got one

Comment: math.degrees() and math.radians() essentially perform the direct opposite operation, leaving you with what you started with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost there! math.degrees takes in a number in radians, so `math.degrees(1)` will give you the answer (57.295779...)

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: @AustinKennedy After you get a good answer to your question, you should accept it by clicking the hollow check mark below the voting arrows to the left. See [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) You can also vote up or down with the solid grey arrows.